# Error when trying to calculate correlation

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataset and I have 5 variables of interest. I am trying to find the correlation between these variables, but I am getting an error message.

This is what I put in (after reading in the data set, of course):

```
cor("EducationYears", "DecisionSpending", na.rm = TRUE)

Error Message:
Error in cor("EducationYears", "DecisionSpending", na.rm = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

So I tried this:

```
cor("EducationYears", "DecisionSpending")
```

And got:

```
Error in cor("EducationYears", "DecisionSpending") : 'x' must be numeric
```

The issue to me is that these two variables ARE numeric. There are some `NA`s in there, but I thought `na.rm` would fix that?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Would help to see some example data and how you read it into R.

Comment: You're typing in quoted strings, not variables, so it's trying to correlate the names, which is obviously failing. Also, `cor` has a `use` parameter instead of `na.rm`; see `?cor` for how it works.

Comment: The variable names should not be in quotes: `cor(EducationYears, DecisionSpending)`